# Projection in pst-solides3d doesn't work

Tags: pst-solides3d

I just started to learn how to use pst-solides3d. When I try to project text onto a plane following the instructions in the manual

```
    \documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-solides3d}

    \begin{document}

    \psset{viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
    \psset{unit=0.4}

    \begin{pspicture}(-8,-7)(4,9)
    \psset{solidmemory}
    \psSolid[object=cube,a=8,action=draw,linecolor=red,name=A]%
    \psset{fontsize=200}
    \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 0,name=P0]
    \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=gray,text=A,plan=P0]%
    \psset{phi=90}
    \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=A,plan=P0]%
    \axesIIID(4,4,4)(6,6,6)
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

but instead of the supposed output as shown in the above picture, the program gives back console output which indicates an error

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
(untitled-3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/latex-tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Loading pgffor.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.t
ex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometri
c.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.
tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.c
ode.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.te
x)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.t
ex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.te
x)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarith
metics.code.tex)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex)))
`PSTricks' v3.01a  <2021/03/30> (tvz,hv)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstricks.con
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstricks.con
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks-xetex.def)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pst-solides3d\pst-solides3d.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-solides3d\pst-solides3d.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-node\pst-node.tex
 v1.42a, 2020/04/01)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/multido\multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>) `PSTSOLIDESIIID' v4.34a, 2018/12/27))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def ())
(untitled-3.aux) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd)
[1] (untitled-3.aux)Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   ISO-Font   NimbusSanL-ReguCond
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1967   3   7   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:989/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:122/200(L)--   --dict:778/1012(L)--   --dict:218/300(L)--   --dict:778/1012(L)--   --dict:1/2(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 11798
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!
By the way, I use Texworks on windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly is your problem? I obtain exactly the same result as in your image.

Comment: @Bernard Do you have a completely up-to-date installation? I do reproduce the OP's errors on a fully updated TeXLive 2021 installation.

Comment: @user241086: I think so: pstricks 3.01 (2021/03/30) and pst-solides3d 1.42 (2020/04/01),but I'm under MiKTeX. XeTeX is in version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993.

Comment: @Bernard And you compile with `xelatex`? (Please note that things get slightly better on my machine when compiling with latex, converting dvi to ps and ps to pdf, but errors still occur and I only get the gray but not the red projection, nor the axes.)

Comment: Yes I compile directly with xelatex. – 0  errors, 0 warnings.